# Using clang-cl with an NMake style Makefile cannot echo

Tags: makefile, clang, nmake, cl

I have an existing Makefile (for NMake and not GNU) that works fine with the default CL compiler. I was going to experiment with Clang using the clang-cl compatibility program. But I seem to get errors in the Makefile that are not related to the compiler. For example, I have a code fragment in the Makefile

```
MAKHDR=$(MAKDIR)header.$(MAKEXT)
!if ![(echo HDR=\>$(MAKHDR)) && for %i in ($(HDRDIR)*.$(HDREXT)) do @echo %i\>>$(MAKHDR)]
!include $(MAKHDR)
!else
!error Cannot locate header files
!endif
```

From the command line

```
set CXX=clang-cl
nmake
```

This code is supposed to locate all the header files and put them in a variable (sort of like the wildcard macro in GNU Make). But I get the "Access is denied" error before the !error above fires and the named "header" file does not exist on disk afterward. In fact, with subtle change to the code I found that I cannot echo to stdout either. But it works when I do it with the default CL. So why does the compiler override change the ability to echo?

If you're interested the full Makefile can be found on my [GitHub](https://github.com/JesseMaurais/Oasys/blob/master/.make.cc) but be warned that it is unconventional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following two lines in the `.make.cc` file:

```
DIR=\ //
ENT=;
```

The second line looks odd, but is correct: it is used to specify the Windows list separator `;` instead of the Unix `:`. The goal of the first line is to set `$(DIR)` to be a single backslash, `\`.

`cl` in creating `.make` generates:

```
DIR=\ ^M$
ENT=;^M$
```

(with `^M` and `$` added for clarity) while `clang-cl` strips off the white space at the end of each line and generates:

```
DIR=\$
ENT=;$
```

So with `cl`, `$(DIR)` expands to just a single backslash `\`, as desired. But in `clang-cl` it expands to  `ENT=;`, which causes the filename `$(MAKHDR)` to become `obj ENT=;header.mak` rather than `obj\header.mak`.

Alse `$(HDRDIR)` becomes `src ENT=;`, spoiling the `for %i in ($(HDRDIR)*...`.

---

One solution is to replace in `.make.cc`:

```
DIR=\ //
```

with

```
DIR=\ #
```

(I also tried using `^\`, but that was a disaster.)

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thank you.